# REGEX for Any Character except more then 3 repeats of any

Tags: regex

I have this REGEX which will return true if hitting more then 3 of any character.

```
/(.)\1{3}/g
```

I need to reverse this statement in regex so it returns false if there are more then 3 repeats of any character, allowing for any characters to be entered.

Comment: what language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead to ensure that more than 3 consecutive characters are not found anywhere in the string:

```
(?!.*(.)\1{3})^.*$
```

[Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/vk20JW/2)